# How to split a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, nested, multidimensional-array

How can I take a multi-dimensional array like the below, and split it into multiple separate arrays? Additional challenge: Although I know there are two pairs in the example below (pageviews, visits), how can you do it assuming that you don't know the number of pairs in the array? For example, I may want to add "time on page" or "pages visited", and could therefore have any number of pairs.

My goal, in the end, would be to have an array like: "26, 9, 18" and another array "20, 4, 9".

I've got an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [20090817] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 26
            [ga:visits] => 20
        )

    [20090818] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 9
            [ga:visits] => 4
        )

    [20090819] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 18
            [ga:visits] => 9
        )
)
```

I would have thought the below code would work, but it doesn't get the specific value that I want, and for some weird reason, it trims each value to one character:

```
$pageViews = array();
$visits[] = array();
foreach ($google_lastMonth as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $nested_key => $nested_value) {
        $pageViews[] = $nested_value["ga:pageviews"];
        $visits[] = $nested_value["ga:visits"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, nothing obviously wrong with the way you're doing it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your array is not as deep as you think:

```
$pageViews = array();
$visits = array();
foreach ($google_lastMonth as $value) {
    $pageViews[] = $value["ga:pageviews"];
    $visits[] = $value["ga:visits"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!! Dear lord, I hate these "gotchas". Thank god for stackoverflow, and you kind folks who make things work ;D

Answer (score 0):

I think

you should erase the braket on visit

Ok my bad should be that

```
  $pageViews = array();
    $visits = array();
    foreach ($result as $value) {
    $pageViews[] = $value['ga:pageviews'];
        $visits[] = $value['ga:visits'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I'm still having the problem though. Any other ideas?

Comment: try to replace the " by ' on

 $pageViews[] = $nested_value['ga:pageviews'];
        $visits[] = $nested_value['ga:visits'];

Comment: hehe too late ... I should open my eyes time to time ^^